# Java: toString error "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String"

Tags: java, tostring

I just need a quick help with my `toString`. This involves playing cards.

```
public class Card
{
  //Data
  private int rank;
  private char rank2;
  private char suit;

  //more codes (constructor etc.)

  //toString
    public String toString ( )
    {
    if (rank == 11)
        rank2 = 'J';
    else if (rank == 12)
        rank2 = 'Q';
    else if (rank == 13)
        rank2 = 'K';
    else if (rank == 14)
        rank2 = 'A';
    else
        return rank2 + suit; // <----error here.
    }
```

I am trying to figure out how to return a rank and a suit. For example, if someone were to input 11 for the rank and 'S' for the suit, then I should return a JS. However, I am running into an error:

> "error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to String"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding two `char`s together actually adds their unicode values and returns an integer. If you wish to instead concatenate them together as a `String`, then do the following:

```
return rank2 + "" + suit;
```

This will form a `String` and append `suit` to the end of `rank2`. So if `rank2` was 'J' and `suit` was 'H', "JH" would be returned.

Comment: A `char` is not an ASCII value. It is a Unicode/UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: Looks like clarification by Tom Blodget has since been corrected/edited into this Answer.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, `char` type is treated as `int`. `char` type supports arithmetic operation, so they can be added. So when you use + operator, it adds their values. But because `char` type and `int` type are different primitive types, they are incompatible for arithmetic operation.

If you need string concatenation then you need to change your code to:

```
return String.valueOf(rank2) + String.valueOf(suit);
```

Comment: This answer could be improved if it explained exactly why the OP is getting the incompatible types error

Comment: Looks like improvement per DNA ^ comment has been successfully edited in now.

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way for this would be following

```
return new StringBuilder(rank2).append(suit).toString();
```

Here only one object is created and solves the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

the thing is that char can be read as an int value. When trying to perform arithmetic functions on character, it will be using the byte value of the character. Java cannot implicitly cast a int into a String since String is not regarded as a primitive data type in Java. You need to use .valueOf() method of the String class in order to explicitly tell Java that you want it as String.

```
String.valueOf(input_your_value_here);
```